# select creation script of a view or materialised view

Tags: oracle, select, view, materialized-views

What I want: I want to make a select statement where the result set to have 2 columns, view name and (blob, long, memo) the creation script of the view

ie: select viewname, viewscript from somesystemtable where viewname like '%Numeric%Values'

```
viewname                 viewscript
------------------------------------------------
AlfaNumericValues        (memo, click to view)
DerivativeNumericValues  (memo, click to view)
```

Comment: That `somesystemtable` would be `[dba][user][all]_views` data dictionary view for views and  `[dba][all][user]_mviews` data dictionary view for materialized views. Find out more about [*_views](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2117.htm#i1593583) and [*_mviews](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1105.htm#i1582466)

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle, you've got to do this:

```
SELECT view_name, text
  FROM user_view
 WHERE view_name LIKE '%VIEWNAME%'; -- The name of the view in all capital letters.
```